# What is 1 scallion?

Tags: onions, measurements

When a recipe calls for 1 scallion / green onion / spring onion, what does it mean?

Is it A (a bundle as sold), B (a bunch of connected shoots), or C (one shoot)?

[image]

Usually I just ignore the count and put in as much as I think makes sense, but I've never actually been sure what the count means.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**B is 1 scallion.**

A is a bunch.

C is just the green part which I usually dispose in favor of the white part you seem to throw out...

Comment: Which part you use is very cuisine dependent - or both parts are used, eg white in the cooked aromatics and green as garnish in a lot of chinese cooking!

Comment: I do a lot of stir-fry, that's probably why the green was my default for those pics. The green parts look nicer and break up the brown-ness. I use the white parts in marinades, sauces, poaching and stuff. Although the green parts are both tasty and beautiful in the sauce at http://www.thekitchn.com/recipe-seared-salmon-with-soy-scallions-and-ginger-224286 (off-topic but, killer simple recipe btw).